# when is the memory released in this function

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have got a view controller which calls a function in another nsobject file.

So in my main view controller i call a function by

[DatabaseFunctions FillArrays: Array];

Array is a nsmutablearray initialised in the view controller.

In DatabaseFunctions.h

```
+ (void) FillArrays : (NSMutableArray*) Array;
```

and in DatabaseFunctions.m

```
+ (void) MainScreenFill : (NSMutableArray*) Array{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbDatabasePath UTF8String], &TableDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        [Array removeAllObjects];

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT VARIABLE, VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2, VARIABLE3 FROM TABLE];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(TableDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                MainTableView *P = [[MainTableView alloc]init];
                [P setFirstname:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
                [P setSecondname:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
                [P setClass:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]];

                [Array addObject:P];
            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(TableDB);
}
```

my question is when is the memory allocation MainTableView *P = [[MainTableView alloc]init]; deallocated?

Comment: `P` is released several times. Do you really mean to ask when it will be deallocated?

Comment: FYI - It is standard convention that only class names being with uppercase letters. Method names and variable names should begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: yes i mean deallocated sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's docs on [Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html):

> When the retain count becomes zero, the object is deallocated (destroyed).

In the scenario you described, any variable assigned to P will not be deallocated, since you are adding it to your array. The array maintains a strong reference to your object, and so it will not be deallocated until that reference is broken (until you remove the object from the array, or the array itself is deallocated).

Comment: so if it is added to an array, that array is created in the view controller. When i leave the view controller (switch screens) it will all be deleted? I have an app with several views, and switching views is causing a memory leak, I'm just trying to establish where.

Comment: That depends if your view controller is deallocated or not - If it's part of a navigation stack, the old one will not be deallocated until it is popped from the stack (i.e. pushing one on top will not trigger dealloc).

Comment: im switching view by using the following code         TableViewSelect *switchviews = [[TableViewSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController: switchviews animated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: "self" in that case will not be deallocated. It is still in memory in case the presented view controller is dismissed.

Comment: so how do i do it properly lol, going though web links thats the solution i found. Any chance you can send a link tutorial or advise?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, your question was about when an object will be deallocated.

Comment: switch views in a way that deallocates the memory of the old view. The nature of the app, views are switched extensively between four views. Every view change is done like the above. Or shall i ask this in a new question?